# Spring Kafka template: Using kafka template Bean vs kafka template instance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Spring Kafka template: Using kafka template Bean vs kafka template instance

I have added wrapper over kafka template to add some common functionality based on my usecase.

Which implemenation of kafka template send method is correct?
send1() or send2().

In send1() : passing the bean reference.
In send2(): using kafka template instance reference.
For me send2() is more clean way of abstraction, only concern is it should not create any problem in future.
Both are able to produce in topic.

```
public abstract class AbstractKafkaTemplate<K, V> {
  private KafkaTemplate<K, V> kafkaTemplate;

  public KafkaTemplate<K, V> createKafkaTemplate() {
    kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(getKafkaProducerFactory());
    return kafkaTemplate;
  }


  public void send1(Message<V> message, KafkaTemplate<K, V> kafkaTemplate) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(message);
  }

 public void send2(Message<V> message) {
    this.kafkaTemplate.send(message);
  }

}
```

```
@Component
public class DemoKafkaTemplate extends AbstractKafkaTemplate<String, String> {

  @Bean(name = "DEMO_KAFKA_TEMPLATE_NAME")
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> createkafkaTemplateBean() {
    return createKafkaTemplate();
  }

}
```

```
@Component
public class DemoProducer {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("DEMO_KAFKA_TEMPLATE_NAME")
  KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;

  @Autowired
  DemoKafkaTemplate demoKafkaTemplate;


 public void send(Event<String> event) {

// use kafka template instance
       demoKafkaTemplate.send1(msg,kafkaTemplate);

// use kafka template bean
       demoKafkaTemplate.send2(msg);
 

 }



}
```

Comment: This won't do what you think it does. I really don't see the added benefit here of the added (broken imho) abstraction.

Comment: `send2()` is fine, but you should use the `KafkaTemplate` bean (e.g. `@Autowire` or add it to the constructor) instead of creating one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`send2()` is fine, but you should use the `KafkaTemplate` bean (e.g. `@Autowire` or add it to the constructor) instead of creating one yourself.

Comment: Thank you for quick response, how can we acheive-"using KafkaTemplate bean in implemention" & keeping the above abstractions. 
If possible, could please help with sample.

Comment: Simply add the template as a constructor parameter to your wrapper class and define the wrapper class as a Bean (or `@Component`); Spring will automatically wire in the template bean.